# How to find the IMEI and serial number of an iPhone before selling it?

Tags: iphone

I am selling away my iPhone 5s as I wish to upgrade to a new one. The IMEI number mentioned on the back side of the device is scratched.

How do I determine the IMEI and Serial Number of the device.

Is there anything else that needs to be taken care of before giving away the iPhone?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of iOS running on your iPhone. You can determine that by going to Settings app → General → About and look for an item titled Version.

Comment: The relevant Apple page, showing most of the various places to find the numbers looked for: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204073

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily determine the IMEI and the serial number by going to Settings app → General → About and looking for fields named **IMEI** and **Serial Number** (along with host of other information).

[image]

There's also an Apple support document titled [Find the serial number or IMEI on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204073) which is worth going through.

The other **crucial step** to take before giving away your iPhone is to make sure you have synced all your important data (Contacts, Photos, Notes etc.) to iCloud. Also, make sure to create a backup of your iPhone if you wish to restore it to a new iPhone. The backup can be created either on iCloud or an Mac or a Windows computer using iTunes.

Once you have backuped up all the important user data, make sure you **sign out** of iCloud. To sign out of iCloud, go to Settings app, tap on your name shown with profile picture (this should be the first item just below the Search bar), scroll down and tap on Sign Out (last item shown in red).

[image] [image]

You may also be asked to turn off **Find My iPhone**. Do so by tapping on iCloud on the same screen and than tap on Find My iPhone. Toggle to turn off the switch shown in front of Find My iPhone.

[image] [image]

When signing out, iPhone prompts you to choose between deleting or keeping data (Contacts, Notes, Reminders etc.) locally on device. It is recommended to **delete the data** from device as you are giving it away. As an extra security measure, it's recommended to **factory reset** the device. Do so by going to Settings app → General → Reset and tap on Erase All Content and Settings. You may be prompted to provide the device passcode.

[image]

Once the device is erased, do not set it up again before giving away. It is possible to see the IMEI number even on an iPhone that isn't setup.

It's recommended to go through the Apple support document [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201351) and make sure to follow all the official guidelines.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing the instructions. Let me follow them one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the easy to understand information and instructions. I was able to follow them and have reset the iPhone.

Comment: The ICCID is unique to your SIM card and should also be blacked out.

Comment: @DoubleD I'm not sure how sensitive the ID is, but it's still visible in the edit history. If necessary a mod could help altering the history so this isn't possible anymore. I'll leave it to Nimesh to decide whether that's worth a mod-flag.

Answer (score 1):

Just type *#06# from you iphone to get your IMEI no.